# What would happen if electrons were spin-1?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, periodic-table

We were speaking about this in class, but I can't understand it quite well. What would happen if (hypothetically of course) the allowed $m_s$ values were $-1$, $0$ and $1$? What impact does this have on our current Periodic Table? What impact does it have on the other quantum numbers?

I don't see any relation between $m_s$ and the other quantum numbers... which is why I'm asking so I can really understand it.

Comment: *"I don't see any relation between m_s and the other quantum numbers"* You're right; there isn't any. This is an unfortunate choice of spin, though: the Pauli exclusion principle, which guarantees that no two electrons have the same quantum numbers, doesn't work for particles that have integer-valued spins. Google bosons, fermions, and the spin–statistics theorem for more info. Presumably, the question (incorrectly) assumes that the Pauli exclusion principle will still hold, and therefore the 1s orbital can hold up to three electrons, etc., making the Periodic Table look rather different.

Comment: ...while in fact this would make the 1s orbital capable of holding _all them electrons_, which in turn would make the Periodic Table look yet more strikingly different, and in particular, not periodic at all.

Comment: @Orthocresol so just to reiterate - if the Pauli exclusion principle were to be hypothetically upheld with this change, then the other quantum numbers, subshell letters, etc. and their values would still remain unchanged? The only evident change would be the periodic table being shifted weirdly in order to fit 3, 9, or 13 electrons in each orbital? I'm not sure if the 9 and 13 are correct but I don't understand how I would calculate how many electrons could fit per orbital with this change in m_s values.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin I don't understand how the 1s orbital would be able to hold all electrons because of this change... could you explain that?

Comment: This is because the Pauli exclusion principle would not hold with bosons.

Comment: @diana it has to do with quantum mechanics and is better explained in physics SE than here. Put very briefly, if identical particles have half-integer spins then they come with a symmetry that makes them interfere destructively and cancel out if two of them are in the same state. But integer spin comes with the opposite symmetry and constructive interference, so the identical particles are "attracted" to the same state instead. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle.

Comment: If electrons had the integer spin, there would be nobody asking what if they had spin 1/2. They would all like to sit in 1s orbital, until repulsion would force some to take higher orbitals and grouping would repeat. There would be no bounds as we know, but very different, if any.

Comment: Perhaps the question was formulated so that the answer is "there won't be periodic table". There won't be elements.

Comment: @diana the Pauli exclusion principle is a direct *consequence* of electrons having non-integer spin. It is not separable from that idea and you cannot reintroduce it.

Comment: The simplest answer is that, if electrons had spin 1, there would be no chemistry and no universe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues here which should be carefully disentangled.

1. **Is $m_s$ independent of the other quantum numbers $n, l, m_l$ or do they affect one another?**

It is independent. The reason is because $n, l, m_l$ are quantum numbers which deal with the *spatial coordinates* of the electron, i.e. its position and momentum in 3D space as given by (for example) $(x, y, z)$-coordinates. On the other hand, *spin* is a separate property, often called an "intrinsic angular momentum" which cannot be visualised in 3D space.*

In nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, the Schrödinger equation actually only describes the spatial part (i.e. $n, l, m_l$); the spin part is just tacked on to that at the end. The spin and spatial parts of a wavefunction are completely separate from one another and don't directly interact. (Indirectly they still do, via things like the Pauli exclusion principle.)

2. **Can spin-1 electrons *really* support chemistry?**

As mentioned in the comments, spin-1 particles (and more generally, particles with integer spin, i.e. [bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson)) do not obey the [Pauli exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle). In the context of an atom, that means that two "spin-1 electrons" can share the same four quantum numbers $(n, l, m_l, m_s)$.†

However, the Periodic Table, and chemistry generally, crucially depends on the Pauli exclusion principle. Consider the case of lithium: we say it has an electron configuration of $\mathrm{1s^2 ~2s^1}$. Why does the third electron go into the $\mathrm{2s}$ orbital? Well, it's because the first two went into the $\mathrm{1s}$ orbital, and thus have quantum numbers $(1, 0, 0, +1/2)$ and $(1, 0, 0, -1/2)$. Since the third electron can't share all four quantum numbers with either of its two predecessors, it's forced into the next-lowest orbital, i.e. $(2, 0, 0, \pm 1/2)$ (the sign is irrelevant).

With spin-1 electrons there is no such constraint, so *every* spin-1 electron would simply sit in its lowest possible energy state, namely the $\mathrm{1s}$ orbital.‡ The true electronic configuration of the $n$-th element would then simply be $\mathrm{1s}^n$. So, chemistry as we know it would not exist.

3. **If the Pauli exclusion principle still held for bosonic spin-1 electrons, what would happen?**

This is the easy part: each orbital would just hold three electrons instead of two. So the 1s orbital would hold up to 3 electrons. The 2p subshell would hold 9 electrons (3 orbitals of 3 electrons each). The 3d subshell would hold 15 electrons.

Consider the 2–8–8–18... pattern that we see in the (normal, spin-1/2) Periodic Table:

- 2 comes from the 1s orbital (2).
- 8 comes from 2s + 2p (2 + 6).
- 8 comes from 3s + 3p (2 + 6).
- 18 comes from 4s + 3d + 4p (2 + 10 + 6).

In hypothetical spin-1-electron land with hypothetical Pauli exclusion principle, this would be 3–12–12–27:

- 3 comes from 1s orbital (3).
- 12 comes from 2s + 2p (3 + 9).
- 12 comes from 3s + 3p (3 + 9).
- 27 comes from 4s + 3d + 4p (3 + 15 + 9).

It's not hard to see that these numbers are just the previous numbers multiplied by $3/2$.

---

**Footnotes**

* You may have seen oversimplified depictions of spin as the electron rotating about its own axis, like how the Earth rotates to cause the day/night cycle. These depictions are all incorrect and physically unreasonable.

† Note that the Pauli exclusion principle refers to particles that are *identical*, or *indistinguishable*. Two electrons on the same atom are indistinguishable, and thus cannot share the same four quantum numbers. Conversely, if we were talking about two separate hydrogen atoms (which *are* distinguishable), then it is perfectly OK for each of the electrons to have the same four quantum numbers.

‡ In fact, this is not entirely true. If you raise the temperature high enough, then some of the electrons will start to occupy higher-energy states. This concept is similar to a Boltzmann distribution, but is more properly defined by [Bose–Einstein statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics). However, the energy gaps between successive orbitals are very large, so at "realistic" temperatures this is not likely to happen.

Comment: The problem with theorising about the Pauli exclusion principle in a world with spin 1 electrons is that the principle itself is intimately connected to the spin. In fact it is a *direct* consequence of non-integer spin and has no *independent* existence. So hypothesising about it independently makes no sense.

Comment: @matt_black Hmm, I don’t disagree, but the question is what it is. You’re welcome to edit my answer to strengthen the wording (if you want to, of course!), or leave it as a comment.

Comment: "Realistic temperatures": Strictly speaking, the difference between $n=1$ and $n=2$ in hydrogen divided by Boltzmann's Constant is about 118,000 K.